# NullPointer Exception when populating JTable

Tags: nullpointerexception

I get following error when I try to load data into JTable.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tfc.cheque.handle.dao.impl.ChequeDAOImpl.getCheques(ChequeDAOImpl.java:23)
    at com.tfc.cheque.handle.ui.ChequeGUI.(ChequeGUI.java:38)
    at TestChequeDAO$1.run(TestChequeDAO.java:30)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)

this is my main class:

```
public class TestChequeDAO {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
    DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
    connection.setUser("");
    connection.setPswd("");

    ChequeDAOImpl dao = new ChequeDAOImpl();
    dao.setConnection(connection);

    List<Cheque> cheques = dao.getCheques();

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            ChequeGUI cgui;
            try {
                cgui = new ChequeGUI();

                cgui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                cgui.pack();
                cgui.setVisible(true);

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });


}
```

}

this is my gui class:

```
public class ChequeGUI extends JFrame {

JTable guiTable = new JTable();
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new String[]{"Name","Amount","Date"});

public ChequeGUI() throws SQLException {

    guiTable.setModel(model);
    add(new JScrollPane(guiTable));

    //Populate Table
    ChequeDAOImpl chqdi = new ChequeDAOImpl();
    List<Cheque> cheques = chqdi.getCheques();

    for(Cheque cq : cheques){
        model.addRow(new Object[]{cq.getName(),cq.getAmount(),cq.getDate()});
    }


}
```

}

this is where i have written the query:

```
public class ChequeDAOImpl implements ChequeDAO{
//DB2 connection
private DBConnection dbConnection;

public List<Cheque> getCheques() throws SQLException{
    List<Cheque> cheques = new ArrayList<Cheque>();
    Connection connection = dbConnection.getConnection();
    try{
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select * from LIB.DATA");


        while(result.next()) {
            Cheque cheque = new Cheque();      
            cheque.setAmount(result.getDouble("AMOUNT"));
            cheque.setDate(result.getDate("DATE"));
            cheque.setName(result.getString("NAME"));

            cheques.add(cheque);

            for(Cheque chq : cheques){

                System.out.println("Name: " + result.getString("NAME"));
                System.out.println("Amount: " + result.getDouble("AMOUNT"));
                System.out.println("Date: " + result.getDate("DATE"));
            }               



        } 
    }catch(Exception exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        connection.close();
    }
    return cheques;
}

public DBConnection getConnection() {
    return dbConnection;
}

public void setConnection(DBConnection connection) {
    this.dbConnection = connection;
}
```

}

Comment: It is nothing to do with JTable. What is the line 23 in class `ChequeDAOImpl`?

Comment: that is the database connection

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `DBConnection dbConnection`, and that much depends on a way how your application works

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I initialized the dbconnection. But still it is not working.